# How to fix System, Control panel etc. after November update of Windows 10 and prevent Explorer.exe crashes?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, updates

I have been plagued by Microsoft Windows 10 November update like many of you. First, my UI language was reverted to Croatian, with which I can't use windows normally(even though it is my native). This was resolved by manually installing English(US) language pack. You have to find it online and download to your PC. Try searching with your Windows build version number(in settings-system-about computer), desired language pack, x86 or x64, and "download" as a phrase in Google. After that downloaded go through these:
1. Hit Win + R
2. type "lpksetup" and hit Enter
3. do the math, choose the downloaded file and go on from there
+ still, you may have to change something - for example, you'll maybe have to run "gpedit.msc" and there find Regional settings and **disable** (Computer configuration-Administrative templates-Control Panel-Regional and Language options-**Force selected system UI language to overwrite the user UI language**

Second, and more problematic was, I couldn't open File Explorer, System, Control Panel...and you probably know how frustrating it is. The answers I have found online all led me on the way of reseting PC or reinstalling Win10 all over again. And I didn't want to do that. After all, I have a lot of stuff, including programs and games on my PC that I didn't want to reinstall, or lose progress in.
So after reading a lot for the last few days I started snooping around in Registry.
I have found out that by removing BagMRU and BAGS I managed to solve everything. So, right now everything is functioning fine all over again. No need to reset PC or reinstall everything.
Here are the steps:

1. Hit Win + R
2. type "regedit" and hit Enter
3. find and delete these in the registry:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell**BagMRU**]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell**Bags**]

Everythinng should be ok now...
I hope I helped...
Bye!

Comment: This is helpful information, but this is a Q&A site and not a forum.  You should search for a possible question where this answer may fit, or post this in a forum-type place.

Comment: It is sort of a question... :-) I have manged to put the pieces together by reading an answer on this site. So I wanted to make it easier to find for everyone by binding everything that I found out during the last few days...it was a torment to discover what needs to be done. Microsoft is silent about this...and their answers for this problem related questions don't reslove anything.

Comment: @Nikica : This "Question" does not follow the design of how this site is intended to be used.  The biggest problem is that you try to include the "Answer" in the "Question" section.  Answer details should be in an actual "Answer" (which can be written by you).

Comment: Well, ok then. What can we do? Do I remove it?

Comment: First, I suggest you read the help center, especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) Then, you can create an answer for the answer portion of your post and edit your question to be just a (well-defined) question.

Comment: If you intend to post this as a self-answered question, then you actually have two questions here, with two separate resolutions: (1) Your UI language reverted to Croation, and (2)  you were unable to open File Explorer / System / Control Panel.

Comment: And if the reason why you were unable to access the **Manage optional features** settings page, was because you couldn't open Control Panel, then you should add a link from question 1 to question 2.

Comment: What happened when you tried to open File Explorer?